# Kupfer cannot seem to use actions activated in config page

Tags: 16.04, launcher, i3-wm, kupfer

I've been using i3wm for a while and I was just checking some cooler d menu and I ended up with Kupfer.

It looks amazing but the only issue I can't seem to use actions of activated modules.
For example, I activated the apt module and it is shown on the menu when I type apt but I cannot find a way to use install action.
Did I understand something wrong or is there a keyboard shortcut or something?